# Oracle 10.2g Character Set Migration

Tags: oracle

I am in the process of changing the character set for our database. I have a couple questions with regard to the in-place migration using the CSALTER script and performing the full import/export. According to the Oracle documentation, the use of the CSALTER script requires that

> it can be used only if all of the schema data is a strict subset of the new character set
>   
> Source:[Changing the Database Character Set of an Existing Databasee](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch11charsetmig.htm#CEGDHJFF)

The current character set is WE8ISO8859P1. However, I want to change it to AL32UTF8. Is WE8ISO8859P1 a subset of AL32UTF8?  And judging by experience, is it preferable to perform the migration using the CSALTER script as opposed to doing a full export/import?

Comment: Voted to migrate to Database Administrators

Comment: Didn't realize there was a DBA stackoverflow. That is the place my question should be posted at. Can I move it over there or does someone else need to do it?

Comment: @JohnF., you can flag your question for a moderator to move it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, WE8ISO8859P1 is a subset of AL32UTF8, though a small bit of conversion might be needed (which CSALTER will deal with & CSSCAN will inform you of when you do a preliminary scan).

A must-read for Oracle 10.2 is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch11charsetmig.htm#sthref1441).

Doing a full export/import will be more time-consuming than using csscan/csalter.

Another good, albeit old, read is the [Oracle Character Migration Best Practices](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/globalization/twp-character-set-migration-best-pr-128766.pdf) white paper.